# AJAX does not return object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am using AJAX GET to get a local JSON file and it does that, but once i try to return it says undefined.

```
ScoreHandler = function () {
    this.getScores = function() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                //This logs object
                console.log(data); 
                return data;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "JSON/Scores.json", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    };
};

HighScores = function (scoreHandler) {

    var scoreHandler = scoreHandler;
    var scores = this.scoreHandler.getScores();
    //This logs undefined
    console.log(scores); 
}
```

Comment: You can't return data from an `async` call. rather use `callbakcs` to use that response.

Comment: you can use an promise?

Comment: undefined because it is handled asynchronously. So it will take some time to return the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement a callback for `response`, something like this

```
ScoreHandler = function () {
    this.getScores = function(callback) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                //This logs object
                console.log(data); 
                if(typeof callback === 'function')
                   callback(data);
                //return data;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "JSON/Scores.json", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    };
};

HighScores = function (scoreHandler) {

    var scoreHandler = scoreHandler; //why this line use it directly
    var scores = this.scoreHandler.getScores(function(data){
        console.log("response", data); //you can see the data here
    });
    //This logs undefined
    console.log(scores); 
}
```

Comment: I'm glad, this helped you :).